# Selector jQuery: elementos que contengan elementos cuyo value no sea nulo

Tags: jquery, select

Obtengo el siguiente elemento HTML a traves de la funcion "jQuery('fieldset.ame-fieldset')"

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="webform-component-fieldset ame-fieldset ame-fieldset-more webform-component--fieldset-wrapper form-wrapper">
<div class="fieldset-wrapper">
<fieldset class="webform-component-fieldset ame-fieldset ame-fieldset-more webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset0 form-wrapper">
   <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset0--productosServiciosDeLaEmpresa0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-productosserviciosdelaempresa0">Productos/Servicios de la empresa </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-productosserviciosdelaempresa0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset0][productosServiciosDeLaEmpresa0]" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset0--solucion0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-solucion0">Solución </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-solucion0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset0][solucion0]" value="Edinn® Plataforma Industria 4.0 es la solución más completa para el control y la gestión global de la producción." size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset0--necesidad0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-necesidad0">Necesidad </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-necesidad0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset0][necesidad0]" value="Conocer y gestionar en tiempo real lo que ocurre en cualquier industria: productividad, KPI&#039;s, mermas, desviaciones, rrhh, etc." size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset0--beneficios0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-beneficios0">Beneficios </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-beneficios0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset0][beneficios0]" value="ROI &lt; 1 año. Control en tiempo real de todo lo que ocurre en la industria con reducción de costes y mejora de productividad" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
   </div>
</fieldset>
...
...
...
<fieldset class="webform-component-fieldset ame-fieldset webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset1 form-wrapper">
   <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset1--productosServiciosDeLaEmpresa0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-productosserviciosdelaempresa0">Productos/Servicios de la empresa </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-productosserviciosdelaempresa0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset1][productosServiciosDeLaEmpresa0]" value="asdasd" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset1--solucion0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-solucion0">Solución </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-solucion0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset1][solucion0]" value="asdas" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset1--necesidad0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-necesidad0">Necesidad </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-necesidad0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset1][necesidad0]" value="asda" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset1--beneficios0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-beneficios0">Beneficios </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-beneficios0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset1][beneficios0]" value="asd" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

y quiero seleccionar solo aquellos "fieldset" que contengan algún "input" cuyo "value" no sea nulo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes seleccionar todos los `fieldset` y filtrar aquellos que tengan algún `input` con `value` vacío:

```
$('fieldset').filter((i,x)=> $(x).find('input[value=""]').length)
```

Mira este ejemplo:

```js
$(function(){
  var vacios = $('fieldset').filter((i,x)=> $(x).find('input[value=""]').length);
  console.log(vacios.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fieldset-wrapper">
<fieldset class="webform-component-fieldset ame-fieldset ame-fieldset-more webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset0 form-wrapper">
   <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset0--productosServiciosDeLaEmpresa0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-productosserviciosdelaempresa0">Productos/Servicios de la empresa </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-productosserviciosdelaempresa0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset0][productosServiciosDeLaEmpresa0]" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset0--solucion0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-solucion0">Solución </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-solucion0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset0][solucion0]" value="Edinn® Plataforma Industria 4.0 es la solución más completa para el control y la gestión global de la producción." size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset0--necesidad0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-necesidad0">Necesidad </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-necesidad0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset0][necesidad0]" value="Conocer y gestionar en tiempo real lo que ocurre en cualquier industria: productividad, KPI&#039;s, mermas, desviaciones, rrhh, etc." size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset0--beneficios0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-beneficios0">Beneficios </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset0-beneficios0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset0][beneficios0]" value="ROI &lt; 1 año. Control en tiempo real de todo lo que ocurre en la industria con reducción de costes y mejora de productividad" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
   </div>
</fieldset>
...
...
...
<fieldset class="webform-component-fieldset ame-fieldset webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset1 form-wrapper">
   <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset1--productosServiciosDeLaEmpresa0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-productosserviciosdelaempresa0">Productos/Servicios de la empresa </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-productosserviciosdelaempresa0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset1][productosServiciosDeLaEmpresa0]" value="asdasd" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset1--solucion0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-solucion0">Solución </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-solucion0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset1][solucion0]" value="asdas" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset1--necesidad0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-necesidad0">Necesidad </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-necesidad0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset1][necesidad0]" value="asda" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
      <div  class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--fieldset-wrapper--fieldset1--beneficios0">
         <label for="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-beneficios0">Beneficios </label>
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-fieldset-wrapper-fieldset1-beneficios0" name="submitted[fieldset_wrapper][fieldset1][beneficios0]" value="asd" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
      </div>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Es que lo dijo de una forma algo complicada: *y quiero seleccionar solo aquellos "fieldset" que contengan algún "input" cuyo "value" no sea nulo*. Lo que quiere es **seleccionar los `fieldset` que tengan al menos un input que no sea nulo**.

Comment: Cierto. No lo había entendido bien. Corrijo el código.

Comment: Lo que dice que quiere es los `fieldset`... creo que esa parte no está clara. Si quiere los `fieldset` completos (como elementos del Nodo, con todo lo que tienen dentro), o si quiere los inputs de esos fieldset.